# Конвертирование нескольких картинок в массив байт. C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Делаю простую формочку, выбрал фалы - отправил байтами. Хочу упаковать неизвестное количество картинок (открыв диалоговое окно выбрав необходимое количество) в массив байт, не могу пока понять, как правильно сделать. Начал пока так:
Метод конвертер массивов изображений в массив байт:

```
public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image[] imageIn)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            foreach (var img in imageIn)
            {
                img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Вот так открываю файлы:

```
 public string ShowFileDialog(string defaultPath, string filter)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultPath))
                dlg.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(defaultPath);
        }
        catch { }

        dlg.Filter = filter;
        dlg.Multiselect = true;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {



            // Читаю файлы
            foreach (String file in dlg.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    Image loadedImage = Image.FromFile(file);

                    // Тут бы в байты упаковать...

                }
                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

            return dlg.FileName;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

И обработчик кнопки открыть:

```
private void btnSourcePath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = ShowFileDialog(SourceDirectory, sourceFilter);
        if (result != null)
            tbSourcePath.Text = result;
    }
```

Свойство SourceDirectory:

```
public string SourceDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return Path.GetDirectoryName(btnSourcePath.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

И экшн

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // сохранить в бинарник или отправить куда, уже не важно. Важен массив байт картинок 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты можешь создать класс вроде такого:

```
[Serializable]
class ImagesHolder{
    //С сериализацией через рефлексию лучше не использовать автоматических свойств
    //При перекомпиляции имя закрытого поля может измениться
    private int _count;
    public int Count => _count;
    private List<Images> _images;
    List<Image> Images => _images;
    //Тут конструктор и прочее
}
```

Вот в этот класс загружай все свои картинки и сериализуй его через BinaryFormatter в поток. Вот и будет тебе твой массив байтов.

---

Можно обойтись и без класса, но тогда нам нужно будет как-то узнать их число, а при наличии класса это становится удобнее.

---

КРАЙНЕ НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЕТСЯ передавать какие-то данные на другие компьютеры в бинарном формате, так как они могут их представлять по разному, а значит это сильно ударит по универсальности приложения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Буду пробовать. Кстати, число можно будет узнать из dlg.FileNames.Length наверное?

Comment: @JDo, я про то, что будет проблематично узнать число картинок когда тебе придёт набор байт. Ты же должен будешь их обратно расшифровать, а не зная их количества придётся костылить)

Comment: В данном случае это я думаю не нужно. Мне потом массив байт в AVI декодировать.